# Jquery AJAX one by one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to run two ajax requests one after the other. So, I could use the ajax success() function:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {
        //here the second ajax request
    }
});
```

The problem is, that the first ajax request gets only executed, when an condition is true. So my code looks like:

```
if($cond) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
$.ajax({
    ...
});
```

How can I run these request ony by one? Or is it standard that the second gets only executed when the first has finished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery 1.5 introduced [deferred objects *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), and [`$.ajax` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is returning one:

```
$.ajax({
   //...
}).then(function() {
    $.ajax({
        //...
    });
});
```

**Reference:** [`deferred.then` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then)

**Update:**

In your case you can do this:

```
var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
deferred.resolve();  // <- I think you need this here but I'm not sure.

if($cond) {
    deferred = $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
deferred.then(function() {
    $.ajax({
      //...
    });
});
```

Comment: This will not work, because the first ajax request is under the $cond condition whereas the second is not.

Comment: But then the second request only works, when the first request was executed. Mhh, it looks like the best solution is to make the first request synchronous.

Comment: @groh: Have you seen my update? I added `deferred.resolve();`.... or what is not clear? It should work this way.